# Koma-script doesn't do heading skip after longtable

Tags: sectioning, longtable, koma-script

I'm puzzled why Koma-script in certain situations doesn't honor vertical skip before heading if the heading is after `longtable`

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, paper = B5]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}

\begin{document}

\LTpre  = 0pt
\LTpost = 0pt

\chapter{Nam dui ligula}

\section{Curabitur auctor semper nulla}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetuer adipiscing elit\\
    Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut & placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\\
\end{longtable}

\subsection{Morbi auctor lorem}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The resulting subsection heading will be just after the table:

[image]

Now if I remove `chapter` and `section`, suddenly the skip is honored:

[image]

Where is the logic? How to force Koma-script always perform the skip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not related to koma-script, you would see the same with book.

The problem is that you have *only* a longtable between `\section` and `\subsection` and this doesn't trigger the change of the `\if@nobreak` conditional.

```
\documentclass[12pt, paper = B5]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}

\begin{document}

\LTpre  = 0pt
\LTpost = 0pt

\chapter{Nam dui ligula}

\section{Curabitur auctor semper nulla}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetuer adipiscing elit\\
    Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut & placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.\\
\end{longtable}

\makeatletter \@nobreakfalse \makeatother %added
\subsection{Morbi auctor lorem}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I should fix that.... longtable doesn't start a paragraph....

Comment: Wow... I wouldn't have guessed it myself. Thanks!